# Can I make Google Sheets use a default theme when I create a new sheet via "Add Sheet"?

Tags: google-sheets

On Google Sheets, I can create a new sheet by clicking the "+" button at the bottom of the page. But this sheet always has the same "theme": white, with gridlines, 1000 rows, etc.

[image: Google Sheet Empty Seet]

I end up re-applying the same styling over and over again.

Is it possible to make Google Sheets use some pre-defined theme whenever I click the Add Sheet "+" button?

Comment: How about Duplicate” instead of “Add”?

Comment: @Tedinoz yes, that would be a solution, but duplicating a spreadsheet would also duplicate its content. I'd prefer to start with a clean slate.

Comment: No content, just a blank, formatted sheet.

Comment: Yes but that would mean I'd have to maintain an empty sheet in all of my spreadsheets. Of course, not a big deal, but my question was specifically about whether Google Sheets supports this feature without resorting to duplication.